# Replace some header strings in Excel with a count value in a given interval VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Here is a minimal example of my Excel sheet:

[image]

**GOAL:**
Column 1 and 2 will always be respectively "Number" and "Stand".
I'm trying to rename the header in column C to the column left to the "TOTAL-column" (which can be in different positions). The names in the aforementioned range should be a counter, Such that the resulting header in the above example would be:
Number, Stand, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, TOTAL.

**ATTEMPT:**
This is what I got so far, however it isn't very efficient, to manually copy the replacement-line for each column, and it doesn't add a header in the empty columns

```
Sub Rename()
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim MatchCase As Boolean
For Each WS In Worksheets
WS.Cells.Replace What:="1,", Replacement:="1", LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=True
WS.Cells.Replace What:="2,", Replacement:="2", LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=True
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm curios why you are trying to do this with VBA. You could make the cell a formula that says =column()-2 or =column()-2&",18"

If you really wanted a vba solution, you could use vba to search for the "total" cell, and then make all cells to the left of it the above formula.

Comment: It's a small part of a larger VBA.
The position of the TOTAL column is unknown and the values in column C to H in the above example can have varying number of decimals but is formatted as a string.